# QGIS keeping settings in sync?

Tags: qgis, command-line

I have several field PCs using QGIS and need to be able to use a thumb drive to re-set each one to the same window, commands, symbols etc.. I have read about the --configpath but am totally at a loss what folder or procedure to implement the "switch". Do i use the settings command in Qgis or is there a folder i need to place these in?

Answer (score 1):

We have a process in place that we use on training computers to reset them to a clean state before each session.

We set up one instance of QGIS as a template and went to Settings > Customisation (enabled customisation) and saved the settings to a .ini file.

On each machine we then run a batch file to copy this .ini file from a central location to the machine.

`rem ***************************************
   rem *** Batchfile to copy QGIS INI file ***
   rem ***************************************
   cd c:\temp\qgis2\QGIS
   xcopy /y /path/to/QGIS2.ini`

Then the batch file used to start QGIS is modified to include the option --configpath and the location where we have saved the .ini file. [Note: this must be done on each machine needing the reset]

`start "QGIS" /B "%OSGEO4W_ROOT%"\bin\qgis-bin.exe --configpath c:/temp/qgis2/QGIS %*`

Now when the new user starts QGIS it reads the new ini file and sets the layout and everything else back to the initial state we set up.

See [this post](http://www.qgis.nl/2014/04/22/qgis-in-de-klas-onder-windows/?lang=en) from the Dutch QGIS user group for more information.  After the first effort of setting up one machine it is very easy to reset all the others by running the batch file.  In your situation you could have the ini file and batch file on the thumb drive. Stick it in each machine in turn and run the batch file.

Comment: I've got a feeling the --configpath option has been changed in QGIS 3.0.  It no longer works.